# Twig fails to pass an optional parameter on live enviroment

Tags: php, twig, silex

I have these lines in a twig template:

```
{% for line in order.getItems() %}
    {% set os = line.option.getOverstock(true)|first %}
```

Which refers to this method:

```
public function getOverstock($getQtyOrdering = false) {
        if ($getQtyOrdering === false) {
            return $this->overstock;
        }

        //sort the collection by the quantity field before returning
        $iterator = $this->overstock->getIterator();
        $iterator->uasort(function ($a, $b) {
            return ($a->getQty() < $b->getQty()) ? 1 : -1;
        });
        $sortResult = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection(iterator_to_array($iterator));
        return $sortResult;

    }
```

On my dev environment this is working perfectly, but on live the parameter is not being passed to the method. I've checked the live and dev copies against each other and against our repository - everything looks fine.

How can I debug this situation?

(I'm working in the silex framework)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dump function http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html to output this variable.

Or add symfony package `symfony/var-dumper` by:

```
composer require symfony/var-dumper
```

add dump function to twig

```
$app->extend('twig', function ($twig) use ($app, $request) {
    $twig->addFunction('dump', new \Twig_SimpleFunction('dump', '\dump'));

    return $twig;
});
```

and output this variable in template

```
{% for line in order.getItems() %}
    {{ dump(line.option.getOverstock(true)|first) }}
    {{ dump(line.option.getOverstock(true)) }}
    {{ dump(line) }}
    {% set os = line.option.getOverstock(true)|first %}
```